# How do I use filenames that start with a dash "-" as command arguments?

Tags: command-line, special-characters, filename

This may be a simple question, but how do I use files starting with "-" with command line programs?

For example,  I am trying to use `pdfgrep` on a file named `-2013-01-01.pdf` but it complains that there are no options defined for 2, 0, 1, 3 and so on.

Changing the filename to something that does not start with "-" solves it, but this is not an option since the files aren't created by me. I simply want to check for a specific change I know is coming.

Comment: this dos not work, gives me the same errors as before

Comment: As an example, `grep -i dfv -- -myfile1 -myfile2`.

Comment: that works! thanks! make it n answer and i can mark it as accepted for future generations :)

Comment: @AliNa, did using quotes work for you with pdfgrep specifically? It didn't work for me. I'm using Lubuntu.

Comment: @AliNa: Quotation marks won't work, as they are interpreted by the shell, not the program.

Comment: @AliNa [Quotation marks don't make it work with `cp`, `cd`, or `rm` either.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8594167/) When the shell sees `"-2013-01-01.pdf"`, the argument it passes to a command is still simply `-2013-01-01.pdf`. See [3.1.2 Quoting](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) and [3.5.9 Quote Removal](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal) for details.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. So I'll delete my comments to prevent misinforming others.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very frequently `--` is used on the command-line to signal to a program that no more available command switches are going to be used. This is particularly useful if a file contains a dash, which the program would try to interpret as an option.

1. Without the `--`, there is an error generated:

   ```
   $ pdfgrep -i posix -find.pdf -xorg.pdf

   pdfgrep: invalid option -- 'f'
   pdfgrep: invalid option -- 'd'
   pdfgrep: invalid option -- '.'
   pdfgrep: invalid option -- 'p'
   pdfgrep: invalid option -- 'd'
   pdfgrep: invalid option -- 'f'
   ```
2. With the `--` used we have a successful command:

   ```
   $ pdfgrep -i posix -- -find.pdf -xorg.pdf

   -find.pdf: on the command line. Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk,
   -find.pdf: posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
   -find.pdf: posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
   -find.pdf: posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
   ```
3. `pdfgrep` is programmed to understand `--` to mean that the following command-line arguments are not options. Most programs do the same, but **not all programs understand `--`**. For programs that don't, the solution is to prepend the filename with `./`, like this:

   ```
    pdfgrep -i posix ./-find.pdf ./-xorg.pdf
   ```

   This should work with any command, unless for some reason the command cannot accept a path, only a pure filename.

For a general introduction to the command-line, see [this useful PDF](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php).

Comment: Unfortunately, `--` does **not** work with *all* command-line programs. I had assumed from [that comment by the OP](http://askubuntu.com/questions/278000/how-to-use-commands-with-input-filename-starting-with-character/278003?noredirect=1#comment348923_278000) that `pdfgrep` is one of them that doesn't recognize `--`. But the accept here suggests otherwise. In any case, a program must be coded to recognize `--`. Many programs use libraries to parse their arguments, which do recognize `--`. But some don't, and of those, some are not coded to recognize `--`.

Comment: For those programs that do not recognise `--` the usual workaround is putting `./` in front of the file: `pdfgrep ./-2013-01-01.pdf`

Comment: Yes, putting `./` in front is the most portable and robust solution. Works on any program, on any unix version.

Answer (score 16):

You prepend the file name with `./` (or another relative or absolute path that works).
This way it's portable.

Example:

```sh
for zefile in ./*.tmp
do
   rm -f "$zefile"
done
```

The use of `--` to indicate the end of options is not always available. Some commands will know it, some won't. And this will change across different systems. So in the end, it's less portable.