# How do I delete file named -?]d?j??.? from system?

Tags: command-line, filename

I cannot remove such file, I get error message. file name is

> -?]d?j??.?

and I want to remove it.
I try rm -?]d?j??.? but it gives error.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/278000/how-do-i-use-filenames-that-start-with-a-dash-as-command-arguments

Answer (score 5):

According to manual,

To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use one of these commands:

```
rm -- -foo
rm ./-foo
```

In you case enter:

```
rm -- -?]d?j??.?
```

or

```
rm -- '-?]d?j??.?'
```

Answer (score 2):

First, look at the file with `ls -b ./-*` to see the real filename. You can use `bash` file completion to delete the file:

```
rm ./-
```

Followed by the <kbd>TAB</kbd> character.

Using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> will expand the funny characters in the filename just the way `bash` wants to parse them.

`rm` supports options, introduced by `-`. When it sees your filename beginning with `-`, it gets confused. Putting the name of the current directory ("`./`") in front of the filename means the same file, but the name now starts with a `.`, which doesn't confuse `rm`.